# I echo out data but can't figure out how to concatenate it into a anchor tag

Tags: php, sql

I have this code which takes a user submitted USERNAME, their username is written to a SQL database and is echoed on the index. It works, but I can't figure out how to concatenate the username into a anchor tag.

I have this code so far:

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Tumblr");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . "www." . $row['BlogName'] . ".tumblr.com" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Promo'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
```

I want it to echo in the format of:

```
example.tumblr.com
```

With an anchor tag of:

```
http://username.tumblr.com
```

The username subdomain is dynamic, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create the relevant markup, which in your case is the anchor tag itself!

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Tumblr");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='http://www.{$row['BlogName']}.tumblr.com' target='_blank'>" .  $row['BlogName'] . ".tumblr.com" . "</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Promo'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo '<td><a href="http://www.'.$row['BlogName'].'.tumblr.com">http://www.'.$row['BlogName'].'.tumblr.com</a></td>';
```

Comment: the scheme/protocol is not required, and is not recommended becuase if SSL is ever used all the source code would need to be changed.

Comment: @Adelphia *"When the A element's href attribute is set, the element defines a source anchor for a link that may be activated by the user to retrieve a Web resource. The source anchor is the location of the A instance and the destination anchor is the Web resource."* - Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html - therefore the `http://` is required. If SSL is to be used, all OP needs to do is add the `s` - your comment would also need to be applied to the other answer given. Plus, if used in Emails, most likely would not work correctly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah without the HTTP:// it would redirect them to mydomain.co.uk*www.username.tumblr.com, Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Fred-ii- and Bradley Roberts. You're correct, you can't omit it entirely, but you should simply use `//` to let the broswer know you're anchoring to a different page. You simply do not need the full protocol. The browser will assume the same protocol. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt

Comment: ie `href="//www.'.$row['BlogName'].'.tumblr.com"` works perfectly fine, and is a better idea.

Comment: @Adelphia Yes, I agree with that also. `href="//www.'.$row['BlogName'].'.tumblr.com"` is a better idea. +1